# Different Port Number displayed by server and client for a common Port number

Tags: c, sockets

I have server and client Program written in C, and it is working fine, but I am not able to figure out reason for the behaviour explained below:

**server.c**

```
server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
server_address.sin_port = htons(9374);
server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);  
server_len = sizeof(server_address);    
bind(server_sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_address, server_len);

getsockname (server_sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_address, &server_len);
printf("server port = %d\n", server_address.sin_port); 
printf("Server Waiting......\n");
listen(server_sockfd, 5);
```

**client.c**

```
address.sin_family = AF_INET;
address.sin_port = htons(9374);

int length, result;
length = sizeof(address);

result = connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, length);

getsockname(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, &length);
printf("Connecting to Port = %d \n", address.sin_port);
```

outputs On Server Side:

```
[root@dhcppc1 Socket]# ./server
server port = 40484 
Server Waiting......
```

Output on Client Side:

```
[root@dhcppc1 Socket]# ./client
Connecting to Port = 18576
```

My question is:

Though same the port number (`9374`) and operations are implemented in server and client code, yet Why do they show different port numbers( like 40484 on server and 18576 on client)?

Comment: short answer - you connect on a known port, your session is assigned to other unused ports.  Check the accept and connect man pages, or try http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html  beej is very readable, almost humorous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

getsockname() returns the local port number of the connection. A TCP connection has two port, one for each end of the connection.

Since your client has not called bind() to select a local port, the system chose one at random for you.

So your server program is displaying its own port it is listening to, and your client displays its own port it is sending from.

Note also that you are printing out the port number in network endian format, to print it out in host endian, use ntohs() like this (and similar on the client)

```
printf("server port = %d\n", ntohs(server_address.sin_port));
```

This will make the server print out 9374

If you want to fetch the server port on your client, use getpeername() instead of getsockname() - then again, you already know the server port as that's the port you connected to, 9374.

Comment: @Mike as noted there are 2 ports involved in a TCP connection. As a client you connect TO a remote port FROM a local port. The remote(server) port is usually a well known port, e.g. 80 for HTTP. The local port normally doesn't matter, so having the system select a random port that's available is useful.